# Select For Update query from Node JS

Tags: sql, node.js

Currently i use below code to select details from SQL for my Node JS server. Now i have a requirement where i want to use 'SELECT FOR UPDATE' and i am sure how to proceed with that?

```
pool.connect((err, db) => {
        if(err) {
            console.log("Failed connection to mysql");
            errHandler(err);
        }
        let sql1 = 'select * from user where email = ? and role_number = ? ';
        db.query( sql1 , [ email, role ], (err, result) => {
            if(err) {
                console.log("Error in checking existing email");
                errHandler(err);
            }
            else {
                console.log(result);
                if( result.length > 0 ) {
```

Comment: Do you want to update your record in database? Do not clear what exactly you want?

Comment: Basically i want to execute below two query via Node JS.
I want to use Select for update.

SELECT counter_field FROM child_codes FOR UPDATE;
UPDATE child_codes SET counter_field = counter_field + 1;